# Encoding and decoding in Views

Tags: views

I have a view that accepts a contexual filter.When I pass a value through contextual filter like view/sometext ,it is passed directly without encoding.I need to encode it in the url and decode it before processing it in the view.How can I achieve this?

Comment: What kind of encoding are we talking about?

Comment: base64 encoding

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the view's contextual filter, you would need to select 'PHP Code' in the 'Provide a default value'. Then in code you can specify something like:

```
// get current path
$path = explode('/', current_path());
// make sure the path component exists (replace 1)
if (empty($path[1])) return;
// decode the component (use any function you fancy; replace 1)
return base64_decode($path[1]);
```

The encoding would happen wherever the link exists. If it is a view, you might need to use a module such as [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) in order to rewrite your link.

Answer (score 0):

If it is related to a query string, you probably want this views patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/1652568#comment-10121478